# Handling failing tests due to known bugs in cucumber

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jira

We currently use ruby and cucumber setup. There are some steps failing in the tests(end to end regression tests) due to known bugs. Developers takes sometime to fix them according to their work load and bug severity. How best to deal with these failing tests?

1. Should we tag them with bug ticket numbers and let the those specific tests skip when it runs on CI?
2. Let them fail and mark the build unstable until the dev fixes them how many ever days they take?
3. Is there any other way in cucumber to say these specific tests have a different state other than pass or fail to indicate that its under control?

Comment: IMHO you should fix breaking unit tests as soon as possible. Even better is if you use something like svn hooks or rultor that fails a commit before the buggy code gets into your branch. This way you don't have to raise extra tickets to solve these issues. (I would resolve under the same issue as the fix was implemented under)

Comment: Are the unit tests being written when a bug is reported to confirm the buggy behavior (and document in the test the expected behavior)? If so, would it be better to not write those tests until it's time to fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry..I should have made it clear. The tests I'm referring to are not unit tests but end to end regression tests run against the application daily in CI to make sure the build doesn't fail. The scope is to ensure no existing functionality breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a better solution to suit this need on searching further online. we could mark the test as "pending" so that it wont fail but goes yellow and indicates pending.

https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T58243

The beauty of this is, in future if the bug is fixed and the step doesn't fail anymore, it will indicate about that so we can remove the pending status.

Expected pending 'bug jira-195' to fail. No Error was raised. No longer pending? (Cucumber::Pending exception)

Comment: A place I worked at marked them @broken and excluded the scenarios with that tag in CI.

Comment: True and this is what I was planning to do as well. However there is risk of the tagged test ignored and never running if there are huge number of tests. With the above answer, it is much better because you can always see that tests are in pending state in the reports. Also if the tests were fixed, it will complain to remove the pending state